# Error while restoring data using ClockWorkMode recovery in Micromax a110

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, micromax-a110

So I decided to restore but I got an error

> ```
>   Unable to copy file ./dalvik-cache/system@framework@core-junit.jar@classes.dex
>     Error while restoring /data!
>     I: Can't partition unsafe device: /dev/block/mmcblk1p1
>     I: Can't format unknown volume: /external_sd
>     I: Can't partition unsafe device: /dev/block/mmcblk0p6
> ```

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Have you kept all the blobs under `clockworkmod/`. The real content of files to restore seems to reside there (deduplicated between different versions of the backup), and I got such an error when I didn't put all the blobs from the time I made the backup into place.